# What is best approach for using inno-setup to load a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, exe, inno-setup

Am a bit new to inno-setup and  using it to create my java executable file  and using MySQL as a database file. i just have two question:

First, If a user already has MySQL and i want to detect and load a database. do i use MySQL open database connectivity(odbc)

Second, which approach would be the best for loading/running the script. using a batch file or simply run the script within inno-setup?

i would really appreciate some code snippets

thanks

Comment: 1. let's say I will have MySQL installed, how do you connect to it (how do you find a host/port where it's running, how do you authenticate) if you know nothing about it ? 2. How do you identify your database ? Let's say I'll have a database with the same name and you'll run some scripts and accidentally brake my own DB. 3. Hard to say what is "better". Native API way is always preferred before batch scripting.

Comment: Ok! thanks TLama for input. Am assuming it is on the localhost. the user would enter the port it through input field! Have not really thought about the second point you raised! any advise would be welcome!

Comment: That will never be 100% safe. Even if you create me your database and save some info that you did, the next time when I'll run your installer (e.g. an update), you can find a different server instance running on that location and on that server can be the same named DB which you break just because you assume it's yours. That may be harmful. Yes, you identify it by some unique table/record etc. But, the next (not last) thing are credentials. You cannot assume that the user will keep the same credentials and so the next time you can fail on authentication.

Comment: So, what is your Advice? what do think the best approach would be?

Comment: My suggestion is at most try to detect whether there's a running instance of MySQL, attempt to connect to it with some default credentials, attempt to find a database you think it's yours, but, and that's the important thing, offer to the user a comfirmation.

Comment: seems good to me! i would really appreciate any code snippet.